# Apple push notifications from PHP roadblock

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification

I've been fighting objective c for some time now.
Finally I'm back with familiar PHP. I used the great tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12.
The app is ready and tested as much as I could.

My certificates and everything is in orders, tested with ssl.

However, when trying to send push notification to a sandbox server, nothing gets delivered to the phone.

All I get is

```
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
```

sample_feedback.php from ApnsPHP shows following:

```
php sample_feedback.php
Tue, 05 Mar 2013 10:22:46 +0100 ApnsPHP[10294]: INFO: Trying     ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196...
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Tue, 05 Mar 2013 10:22:49 +0100 ApnsPHP[10294]: INFO: Connected to ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196.
Tue, 05 Mar 2013 10:22:49 +0100 ApnsPHP[10294]: INFO: Reading...
Tue, 05 Mar 2013 10:22:49 +0100 ApnsPHP[10294]: INFO: 38 bytes read.
Tue, 05 Mar 2013 10:22:49 +0100 ApnsPHP[10294]: INFO: New feedback tuple: timestamp=1362473808 (2013-03-05 09:56:48), tokenLength=32,     deviceToken=xxxxxfd75e9bf7d13324xxx1f6cc8e885a7c3a5fbba9234546715208cdxxx.
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["timestamp"]=>
    int(1362473808)
    ["tokenLength"]=>
    int(32)
    ["deviceToken"]=>
    string(64) "xxxxxfd75e9bf7d13324xxx1f6cc8e885a7c3a5fbba9234546715208cdxxx"
  }
}
```

My appdelegate has

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
//store message in db for now
}
```

I'm not even sure where to start debugging at this point...

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have created new profile of application and attached same profile after setting apns configuration in Apple Developer Account

Comment: Also, remember to delete application, clean and reinstall on device. And also check that you have added push notification code in your App Delegate class

Comment: i did re-generate profiles. testing with openSSL works OK. I have - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo method. ANything else?

Comment: not sure if it helps. when using ApnsPHP I get prompted to enter PEM pass phrase. When I do, I still get error "unable to connecti to ssl://...'. I'm pretty sure certificates are OK though...

Comment: PEM pass phrase is password you set while exporting to create .p12 file.. Have you entered that correctly?

Comment: it worked for the feedback part...

Comment: what do you mean by feedback part?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25587/discussion-between-selytch-and-p-j)

Comment: still looking for answer. I understand feedback service report means that the notification has not been delivered, but why???